# Jekyll arithmetic in conditional statement

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am trying to do some basic arithmetic in Jekyll's liquid templating engine. I have assigned one variable `numColumns` and I am trying to use it in a conditional statement.

```
{% assign numColumns = 3 %}
```

Note I omitted the outer for loop in the below expression where `loopindex` comes from. Regardless, this works with the `-` operator and correctly evaluates to 2.

```
{% if loopindex == 3 - 1 %}
```

However, these alternatives I tried do not work:

```
{% if loopindex == numColumns - 1 %}
{% if loopindex == numColumns | minus: 1 %}
{% if loopindex == {{ numColumns }} - 1 %}
{% if loopindex == {{ numColumns | minus: 1 }} %}
```

How can I subtract one from `numColumns` in a conditional statement with the liquid templating engine?

Comment: In this specific case it looks like you want `forloop.last`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use filter in liquid `if` expression.

You have to `assign` your calculation to a variable, then use it in your `if` tag.

```
{% assign calc = numColumns | minus: 1 %}
{% if loopindex == calc %}
```